# Capture the text after the third character

Tags: regex, text, mediawiki

I'm editing a wiki and I'm converting some tables into templates.
I've done one manually but it was too tedious.

Basically I have this repeating pattern:

```
|-
|773
|2
|Dictatorship Switch
|
|-
```

`|-` is the separator

1st `|` is the episode number

2nd `|` is another episode number

3rd `|` is the episode title

4rd `|` are some notes

How do I get the episode title, that's after the third `|`?
Then, how would I put them in the following code: `{{Episode|00|Episode Title||||}}`?

Comment: `Then, how would I put them in the following code:` What do you mean by _`them`_ ? What is the `Episode|00|Episode Title|||` and how does that relate to what you need to do ?

Comment: @Maxt8r Since I'm converting to a new format, I would need to create several `{{Episode|00|Episode Title|||||}}` and replace "Episode Title" with each one of the episode titles captured using @Tim Biegeleisen 's regex pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the following regex pattern:

```
^\|-\r?\n\|.*\r?\n.*\r?\n\|(.*)
```

This would capture the episode title in the first (and only) capture group.  Make sure that you run the regex with dot all mode *disabled*.

### Demo